# Tab Equivalent for ListFragment in Android?

Tags: android

I went through the Android Developers class for Fragments, and I really like their explanation and implementation. However, rather than having a list on the left-hand side of the screen that displays content on the right-hand fragment when interacted with, I'd like to show a selection of tabs at the top of the screen.

Is there any sort of equivalent to the ListFragment class for tabs, or a way I can use the Android Developer implementation but to create a group of tabs in the ViewGroup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any sort of equivalent to the ListFragment class for tabs

Not really, as tabs are not usually implemented as a fragment.

> a way I can use the Android Developer implementation but to create a group of tabs in the ViewGroup?

Not really, as tabs are not usually implemented as a fragment.

For tabs, you can:

- use [the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), or
- use `PagerTabStrip` with a `ViewPager`, or
- use the tab flavor of [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) with a `ViewPager`, or
- go retro and use `TabHost` and `TabWidget`, or
- roll something yourself

Comment: I'm probably going to go with TabHost and TabWidget for now; even though it's depreciated, it works until I figure out one of the (presumably) better options you provided above. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: @Argus9: Neither `TabHost` nor `TabWidget` are deprecated. `TabActivity` is, but you do not need a `TabActivity` to use `TabHost` and `TabWidget`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/Tab  However, they are an older style of implementing tabs, which is why I described them as "retro".

Comment: Right you are - I think I mixed them up in a tutorial I read early on in my research for this kind of thing. Thanks again for your input!